# The request is invalid because the app secret is the same as the client token

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

My Facebook app was working fine yesterday, but today it does not work for getting access_token.

My code is:

```
$token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"."client_id=".$app_id."&redirect_uri=".urlencode($my_url)."&client_secret=".$app_secret."&code=".$code;
$response=file_get_contents($token_url);
print_r($response);
$params = null;
parse_str($response, $params);
echo  $params['access_token'];
```

The error is:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "The request is invalid because the app secret is the same as the client token",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 1
   }
}
```

How to solve this issue?

I also used curl, but the response is:

```
object(stdClass)#121 (1) {
    ["error"]=> object(stdClass)#11 (3) {
        ["message"]=> string(77) "The request is invalid because the app secret is the same as the client token"
        ["type"]=> string(14) "OAuthException"
        ["code"]=> int(1)
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you instantiating the `Facebook` object? Please include the code block where this is done. Given the error message, it seems like the values you are passing into the constructor are invalid or incorrect.

Comment: if i use new app_id and app_secret then work properly.......

Comment: can you post an answer to this problem?  what do you mean by if you used a new app_id and app_secret?  did you apply for new ones on the fb dev page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure the client token is different from the app secret (Advanced > Security) and also make sure your application is a web app and not native.

Answer (score 1):

When you receive this error you need to:

1) Set native/desktop app to "No"

[image: Screenshot of Facebook dialog]

2) Reset the previous client token.
[image: Facebook Client Token reset]

3) Put the newly generated token into your app

You can find both of these on the advanced page for your Facebook app's settings:
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[your_app_id]/settings/advanced/

Answer (score 0):

i reset app_secret then work properly and also change Advanced->security to WEB

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems, for several days, i search and search for solutions. But all works when i Set "Native or desktop app" to "No" - in "app->settings->advanced"